# Tratar la excepción: Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/2002)

Tags: php, mysqli, excepciones

Este es el aviso que devuelve la clase mysqli cuando no logra conectarse a la base de datos definida en los parámetros enviados en la creación del objeto:

> Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/2002): No se puede establecer
>   una conexión ya que el equipo de destino denegó expresamente dicha
>   conexión. in [...]

Me gustaría tratar esta "excepción" como si te un error se tratara y he intentando este código:

```
    try{
        $this->conn=new mysqli($db[0],$db[1],$db[2],$db[3]);
    }
    catch (mysqli_sql_exception $e){
        throw $e;
    }
```

Lo que espero es que desaparezca del warning y muestre mi mensaje de error.

Estoy estudiando la documentación, pero no consigo dar con ello:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.errors.php7.php

Ya he probado con:

```
if(!$this->conn=@new mysqli($db[0],$db[1],$db[2],$db[3])){
    echo "No ha sido posible conectar con la base de datos,";
    echo "por favor espere o revise la configuración";
}
```

y tampoco... ¿alguna idea?

¡Gracias!

Comment: Según he leído la clase cuenta con su propia clase para el manejo de excepciones: https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.mysqli-sql-exception.php

Comment: Gracias @phpMyGuel: con la clase de mysqli no he conseguido hacerlo funcionar, pero con el Exception tradicional ha ido bastante bien. Me has puesto en la dirección correcta :) Saludos

Comment: ¡Un placer ayudar!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes que indicarle en el catch la excepción para luego coger el mensaje que lanza.

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);//Considera el warning como un error, y así tratar la excepción.

try {
    $mysqli = new mysqli('127.0.0.1','uesr','password','testDB');
    echo 'connect success';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'ERROR:'.$e->getMessage();
}
```

Puedes poner los mensajes personificados en el `catch`

Prueba de esta manera a ver si te es útil:

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

try{
    $this->conn=new mysqli($db[0],$db[1],$db[2],$db[3]);
}
catch(Exception $e){
    echo "No ha sido posible conectar con la base de datos,";
    echo "por favor espere o revise la configuración";
}
```

Comment: Gracias Mario, para completar la respuesta, añade el `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` para que considere el warning un error y así lo trate como excepción. Así va perfecto... :)

Comment: Gracias a ti por el apunte, me alegra que te haya servido :)